# SQL Server: DATEFIRST Permanent set to Monday

Tags: sql-server, date

I am setting the `DATEFIRST` to start on Monday using this command.

```
SET DATEFIRST 1;
```

My question is: will this permanently set date first to Monday for the entire DB and users? Or will it only affect this one query?

If it only affects the query it is run with, what type of command would I need to permanently change the `DATEFIRST` to Monday for all users/entire DB?

Comment: It affects only the current session: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190356.aspx

Comment: @GiacomoDegliEsposti thank you! Is there a way to permanently change DATEFIRST 1? Or does this need to be ran each session?

Comment: @MidnightPolaris I did that by setting default language for user login. You can also setup dateformat with this option. Check dateformat, datefirst columns in result of query  `select * from syslanguages`

Comment: @MidnightPolaris instead of trying to make the value fixed change your code so it works with any value.

Comment: http://sqlmag.com/t-sql/normalizing-first-day-week

Answer (score 0):

The default first day of week is based on your system setting in Regional and Language setting. By default it is `Sunday = 7` (U.S. English).

As [Microsoft website shows](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181598.aspx), the days are as following:

```
Value   First day of the week is
1       Monday
2       Tuesday
3       Wednesday
4       Thursday
5       Friday
6       Saturday
7       Sunday(default, U.S. English)
```

An example to know which day is the first day:

```
SELECT  @@DATEFIRST                 AS 'First Day',
        DATEPART(dw, SYSDATETIME()) AS 'Today'
```

Comment: Thank you. The system's default is set to day first as Sunday as explained above. I have an assignment that is asking to - Transform the week groupings in order to ensure that the week begins on Monday and not any other day?

is DATE FIRST 1 the best way to do this? Or is there a declare statement that would change this in the DB?

Comment: As I know, No, there is no way!

Comment: Is the affirmation "default first day of week is based on your system setting" still valid? Cause for me that is not correct